# Cannot create ZipArchive in F#

Tags: f#, zip, compression, unzip

I am trying to instantiate a `ZipArchive` class in `System.IO.Compression` in an F# project:

```
open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression
open System.IO.Compression.FileSystem //this line errors, as expected

// Define your library scripting code here

let directoryPath = @"C:\Users\max\Downloads"

let dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath)

let zippedFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles() 
|> Array.filter (fun x -> x.Extension.Equals(".zip"))

let fileStream = new FileStream(((Array.head zippedFiles).FullName), System.IO.FileMode.Open)

//this line does not compile, because ZipArchive is not defined
let archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(fileStream)
```

I can create the same thing in C# in the correct namespace:

```
var unzipper = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(null);
```

(This gives a bunch of errors because I'm passing null, but at least I can try to access it).

I **do** have the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` reference in my F# project (as well as the parent namespace, `System.IO.Compression`. However, when loading the `.FileSystem` namespace, I get an error saying "the namespace 'FileSystem' is not defined".

**EDIT**

Added the full script file I am trying to execute that reproduces the problem.

As shown via the `open` statements, my project references both of these libraries:

`System.IO.Compression`
`System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

I am running on:

- F# 4.4
- .NET 4.6.1
- Visual Studio 2015
- Windows 10 64 bit

**EDIT 2: The Fix!**

I was doing all of this in an F# script file, `.fsx`, which requires telling the interactive environment to load the DLLs like so:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.IO.Compression.dll"
#r "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
#endif
```

Comment: while you need to reference both Compression and Compression.Filesystem, you usually only  `open System.IO.Compression`. Then you  can just say `new ZipArchive(x))` and manipulate it further.

Comment: Please describe the problem you're having with this. Does it fail to compile? If so, what's the error message? Does it fail at run-time? If so, what are the exceptions?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I have updated my question with additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.Compression` to manipulate zip files from .NET 4.5. For some useage examples please see the [relevant docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can just wrap the FileStream into `ZipArchive`, then manipulate it further. The `ExtractToDirectory` extension method is quite handy. You can create a FileStream, instantiate ZipArchive, then manipulate it further, for example by using the `CreateEntryFromFile` extension method, Ideally you should try using `use` on disposable as in the `writeZipFile` example.

Here's an example of reading and writing a zipfile:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.IO.Compression.dll"
#r "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
#endif

open System.IO
open System.IO.Compression

let zipfile = @"c:\tmp\test.zip"
File.Exists zipfile //true

let readZipFile (x:string) = 
    let x = new FileStream(x,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read)
    new ZipArchive(x)

let z = readZipFile zipfile
z.ExtractToDirectory(@"c:\tmp\test")
File.Exists @"c:\tmp\test\test.txt" // true

let writeZipFile (x:string) =
    use newFile = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\newzip.zip",FileMode.Create)
    use newZip =  new ZipArchive(newFile,ZipArchiveMode.Create)
    newZip.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\tmp\test.txt","test.txt")

writeZipFile @"c:\tmp\test.txt"
File.Exists @"c:\tmp\newzip.zip"  // true
```

Comment: It looks like that `if INTERACTIVE` bit is required for this to work property - adding that got everything to tie together. Is this because I am doing this in a F# script file and not a regular F# file?

Comment: @Max yes. Or rather because I assume you are sending this to Fsi, you need the #r directive to reference the dll. If you have (a must) visual f# tools installed yoi can right click on the refernce in vs and select send to interactive. Then just copy-paste the path. You can also generate an include fsx script.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing a reference to `System.IO.Compression.dll`.

`GZipStream` is in the `System.IO.Compression` *namespace*, but the `System.dll` *assembly*.

`ZipArchive` is also in the `System.IO.Compression` *namespace*, but the `System.IO.Compression.dll` *assembly* which may not have been added to your F# project by default.

Comment: I added the reference to the project, both for `Compression` and for `FileSystem`. I still can't access the `ZipArchive` class.

Comment: Strange - with those references, I can get that code to compile fine. (Console app, F# Core 4.4, .net 4.6, VS2015)